# How can I cleanly upgrade an application with a new type of installer?

Tags: .net, windows, inno-setup

I have an application that originally used a Visual-Studio setup project output .MSI installer.  For various reasons, mainly the limited and confusing capabilities of such setup projects, I have created an installer using Inno Script Studio to install the latest version of this app.

It works fine for new installs, but for upgrades, we have some problems.  The client does not want to make their users do an uninstall of the old version before installing the new one.  So, here are my goals for enhancing the new installer to solve some issues with upgrades:

1. Remove the old version of the application from the system in A) the Start Menu, B) The Add/Remove Programs Dialog, C) all shortcut icons pointing to it.  If the new installer is run, it will show two instances of the application in the Add/Remove programs box, and duplicate shortcut icons.  I do not need nor want to remove any of the application's actual files as they can simply be overwritten and some of them *should* be left alone to persist.
2. Check in the Inno script if a component is already installed (Framework EDI.NET, installed by the original app installer) before attempting to install it.

I'd really appreciate your thoughts on how to go about these processes.

Comment: Good Windows Installer practice would be to find the UpgradeCode GUID from the Visual Studio setup MSI, and then use this same code in the new installer. This means you can do a major upgrade from the old installer to the new one. I would give an example but I'm not familiar with Inno.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply have the new installer call the msi package to silently remove the old version. You can do this by calling:

```
msiexec /uninstall <Package.msi|ProductCode>
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx)

After this completes, resume installation as normal. Since you're doing an upgrade, naturally, you'd want to stage any configurations for import into the new version to preserve preferences and whatnot before you remove the old version.

Comment: I'm sure this is by far a better solution if it works for the situation.  In my case, the client is worried about hand-holding many less than savvy users through having to uninstall and reinstall that .NET component (there's an interactive dialog they have to click through for the uninstall).

Comment: Is the EDI.Net component installer also an MSI? If so, you can silently run it with `/quiet`. If that proves difficult because of required user inputs and whatnot, you can even break down the MSI and repackage it to do what you need since MSI are basically just XML manifests with embedded resources. There are lots of tools that let you import MSIs but one such tool is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). Even if it's an EXE, it's common for installer executables to simply be wrappers around MSIs so it shouldn't be too hard to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup is just awesome.  I thought this would be way harder, but didn't even have to write any code!  Sure, there might some extra shortcuts hanging around if the user created them, but largely this will do it.  Add lines like the following:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\UHINt 2.5.lnk"
Type: files; Name: "{userstartmenu}\UHINt 2.5.lnk"
Type: files; Name: "{commonprograms}\UHINt 2.5.lnk"
Type: files; Name: "{userprograms}\UHINt 2.5.lnk"
```

And for the entry in Add/Remove Programs, like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{F0908904-B8CF-46E2-8AA1-2DC981ABDEEE}"; ValueType: none; Flags: deletekey;
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{F0908904-B8CF-46E2-8AA1-2DC981ABDEEE}"; ValueType: none; Flags: deletekey;
```